# String with accents with write_xlsx doesn't work with ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, spreadsheet

I'm trying to use the [write_xlsx](http://cxn03651.github.io/write_xlsx) gem to create an Excel document containing data in French.

I can't figure out how to configure the spreadsheet in order to display **strings containing accents** (typically in UTF-8).
Currently, if I insert strings with accents in some cells, it crashes the whole document (Excel file is blank).

I've noticed that WriteXLSX supports **Unicode** but I can't find how to enable it.

I know that this gem is not very popular but it has advantages that I would enjoy.
Can anyone help me?

**Edit:**
Important information: problem appears only with ruby 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem: it was related with rubyzip.
The creator of write_xlsx nicely updated his gem with a fix.